# Searching -food, on google gives no result

Tags: google-search

I was just fooling around, and was going to search `food` on google. By mistake I entered `-food`, and google gave no results:

> Your search - **-food** - did not match any documents.
>
> Suggestions:
>
> - Make sure that all words are spelled correctly.
> - Try different keywords.
> - Try more general keywords.

I also tried searching other keywords on google with `-` before them. All of them gave no results. I Knew this was because of some part of the algorithm, but could not understand which part.

Can someone tell me is this a bug, or if it isn't, how is this happening? Which part of the algorithm is causing this?

**NOTE:** This is not off-topic for SO as I am asking about the algorithm.  Also giving a space after the `-` gives proper results. Like: `- food`.

Comment: Can you show us the algorithm? Otherwise it *is* off-topic.

Comment: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433

Comment: Can the downvoters explain?

Comment: @AshishAhuja, mostly because it is considered off-topic.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with an algorithm. Your questions is why some people implemented some product in some particular way.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for Super User.

Comment: **This is part of Google search Tricks** http://motto.time.com/4116259/google-search/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it is off-topic. I would answer this, because it will probably get transferred to some other site.

---

Anyways..

You should read the [Google search guide](http://www.googleguide.com/tag/hyphen) then you will understand why this is happening.

This is a feature provided by the Google search engine. When you do not want any word to appear in the results of the search, you use the hyphen just before the word. Something like `-animals`.

Consider this, you would want to search for sports cars without any Ferrari result. So you would type `sports cars -ferrari`

So when you do just `-ferrari` its like entering an empty string in the search box, and asking `ferrari` word to be absent from the results. Obviously the results will be empty, as you entered an empty string to be searched.

---

Giving a space in between, something like `- food` this would actually amount to *searching for food and removing the results with word `<null>`*, since there in nothing after the hyphen. That is why it is giving the proper results.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search#Search_options) or the Google help center it references. For example "- (minus sign) – Exclude a word or a phrase, such as "apple -tree" searches where word "tree" is not used."

So it looked like you ask to search for all documents without giving a keyword but saying that the result should not contain the word food, and Google search decided this was a nonsensical search. Certainly this explains why - food is a different search than -food.